# Getting one select element to affect another

Tags: javascript, html

I recently posted a related question [copying selected option to another select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633025/copying-selected-option-to-another-select).

I realised that what I'm trying to do is more straightforward but I hope I'm not breaking forum rules by "double posting" because this question is slightly different. Here goes. I want "productchoice" to affect "productchoice2".

```
 <select id="productchoice">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="productchoice2">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
```

My question is: when "productchoice" is changed, what javascript should I put in to make "productchoice2" reflect the same choice?

Thanks for your help again, kind people!

Comment: Using pure JS or is jQuery acceptable for this answer?

Comment: And how did your attempt go?

Comment: jQuery is good for me. I tried using function explode() {
    $("#productchoice2").val($("#productchoice").val());
};

And I put onchange into it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="productchoice" onchange="productchoicechange()">
    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
</select>
<select id="productchoice2">
    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

[jsfiddle by index](http://jsfiddle.net/LuaBh/)

```
// by index
function productchoicechange(){
    var productchoice = document.getElementById("productchoice");
    var productchoice2 = document.getElementById("productchoice2");
    productchoice2.options[productchoice.options.selectedIndex].selected = true;
}
```

[jsfiddle by value](http://jsfiddle.net/jppWa/)

```
// by value
function productchoicechange(){
    var productchoice = document.getElementById("productchoice");
    var productchoice2 = document.getElementById("productchoice2");
    productchoice2.value = productchoice.value;
}
```

Comment: when I try going by value I get a blank option on productchoice2

Comment: Take a look at the example jsfiddle for it, it works. So there must be something either different with your code or markup. http://jsfiddle.net/jppWa/

Comment: thanks, doesn't work on the website designer I'm using, but works on Dreamweaver and jsfiddle. Will try to figure it out!

Comment: I got resource interpreted as script but transferred with mime type text/plain on chrome console, do you have any idea why?

Comment: This may help you, but it sounds like the server is serving up the content with the incorrect mime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to use jQuery

```
   $('#productchoice').change(function (){

        $('#productchoice2').val($(this).val());

   });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnwbW/)

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS you can do this:

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('productchoice');

select_element.onchange = function(e){
    document.getElementById('productchoice2').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/Zayq4/

Answer (score 0):

### Try using angularJS

**JSFiddle:-**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/xUPZv/

**HTML:-**

```
<html ng-app>     
    <body>
        <select id="productchoice"  ng-model="selection">
            <option value="1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="2">Option #2</option>
        </select>
        <select id="productchoice2" ng-model="selection">
            <option value="1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="2">Option #2</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```